# Facebook session key using the old rest api

Tags: android, facebook, chat, xmpp

I know this should be on the facebook developer site but I can't seem to register. Anyway I'm using the new api to obtain a access token when connecting to the xmpp chat server but this access token doesn't work; I have to use the old rest api's 'session_key' but I can't seem to find a way to get it. Could someone help me?

I currently use the android facebook sdk but that doesn't have the session key; it only returns an authentication token which doesn't work with my xmpp client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second component of the access token is your session_key

For example if your access-token is

```
***************|a681464febcefb8********-*********|***************
```

Then the middle one is your session_key i.e;

```
a681464febcefb8********-*********
```